# htaccess rule to protect some files independent from from protocoll and host

Tags: .htaccess

I have an htaccess to limit the access to files to a direct click in the website. Copy the link send to another one and open it should be forbid.

My htaccess works well

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://localhost.*$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,R=403,L]
```

Now I tried to make it more variable to protocol and host, but now nobody can access the files. The code should do the same as above only with variable http(s) and localhost part ...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^ - [env=proto:https]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ - [env=proto:http]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^%{ENV:proto}://%{HTTP_HOST}.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,R=403,L]
```

I don't see the error. Can someone help to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change variables to manual entries, will it work?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^(http://|https://)(www.)?(example.com).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,R=403,L]
```

Comment: I added a variable instead of the fixed url, but I think this could work ```RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^(http://|https://)(www.)?(%{HTTP_HOST}).*$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,R=403,L]```

Comment: hmm the htaccess works only if I insert the host by hand. %{HTTP_HOST} does not work ...